# WebFluxTest doesn't resolve requests to controller, if controller implements interface

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-test

There's Spring/Webflux-based REST API server in Kotlin.
All was OK, when there was just a controller.  and the test was working.

But when I changed controller to implement interface, the WebFluxTest cannot resolve the request - it returns error, pretending that URL path not exist.
The test is bound to the controller class, not interface:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@WebFluxTest(PoiController::class)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
```

First version of the controller, this is working in test:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/locations")
class PoiController() 
    @PostMapping()
    suspend fun getLocations(@RequestBody poiRequestDto: PoiRequestDto,
                             @PageableDefault(size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, sort = ["id"]) pageRequest: Pageable):
        ResponseEntity<PageImpl<PoiDto>> {
        
    }
```

Second version - controller implements interface

```
@RequestMapping("\${api.base-path:}")
interface PoiControllerApi {

    @RequestMapping(
            method = [RequestMethod.POST],
            value = ["/locations"],
            produces = ["application/json", "application/problem+json"],
            consumes = ["application/json"]
    )
    suspend fun getLocations(@RequestBody poiRequestDto: PoiRequestDto,
                             @PageableDefault(size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, sort = ["id"]) 
        pageRequest: Pageable):
        ResponseEntity<PageImpl<PoiDto>> {
        
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/locations")
class PoiController(): PoiControllerApi 
    @PostMapping()
    override suspend fun getLocations(@RequestBody poiRequestDto: PoiRequestDto,
                             @PageableDefault(size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, sort = ["id"]) pageRequest: Pageable):
        ResponseEntity<PageImpl<PoiDto>> {
        
    }
```

api.base-path not set, so it's defaulted to "/" . I tried to remove all that @RequestMapping annotations from interface , but result is the same (org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler throws 404 NOT FOUND)

Comment: Does the endpoint still work outside your test? If not, the path is probably interpreted differently. Try to figure out what URL is serving it, and you'll probably find the fix.

Comment: it works in the standalone app